# ng-class not working with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a situation where I have to add class according to the condition and the ng-class is working according to it even the condition in the ng-class is true.

```
<ul id="" class="clowd_wall" dnd-list="vm.cardData[columns.id].data" 
            dnd-drop="vm.callback(item,{targetList: vm.cardData[columns.id].data, targetIndex: index, event: event,item:item,type:'folder',eventType:'sort','root':'folder',current_parent:'folder'})" ng-model="vm.cardData[columns.id].data">
               <div class="emptyCol" ng-if="vm.cardData[columns.id].data.length==0">Empty</div>
              <li class="dndPlaceholder"></li>
              <li class="cont____item" ng-repeat="card in vm.cardData[columns.id].data | orderBy:vm.sort" dnd-draggable="card"
         dnd-effect-allowed="move"
        dnd-allowed-types="card.allowType"
        dnd-moved="vm.cardData[columns.id].data.splice($index, 1)"
        dnd-selected="vm.tree.selected = card"  ng-class="{emptyCard:card.data.length==0,zoomin:vm.zoomin=='zoomin',emptyCard:!card.data}">
                 <div class="item" style="height:79%">
                    <ng-include ng-init = "root = columns.id" src="'app/partials/card.html'"></ng-include>
                 </div>
              </li>
           </ul>
```

Comment: why do you have 2 expressions for `emptyCard` class? you can merge them with `emptyCard : card.data.length==0 || !card.data`

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: HI Mohsin, can you share this json vm.cardData[columns.id].data, So that i can clear understand, where you are making mistake in your code for ng-class.

Answer (score 1):

```
ng-class="{'emptyCard': (!card.data || !vm.cardData[columns.id].data.length),'zoomin':(vm.zoomin=='zoomin')}">
```

Seems like you want to use `vm.cardData[columns.id].data.length` instead of `card.data.length`

Comment: No card has its own data key in it which has some values

Comment: @Mohsinkhan Can you share sample content of `vm`?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear as don't know what card.data will contain  and ".data" will be present for each iteration

If it is array then this will work "card.data.length" and if there is no "data" key in "card" then ".length" will through error i.e. if card.data itself undefined then it will not have "length" property.

Try to add condition in ng-class one by one then you will be able to figure out which condition is causing problem.

Answer (score 0):

Made some small change

```
ng-class="{emptyCard: card.data.length==0 || !card.data,zoomin: vm.zoomin=='zoomin'}"
```

If you have multiple expression, try old fashioned, if it looks best:

**Controller**:

```
$scope.getcardClass = function (objCard, strZoomin) {
    if (!card.data) {
        return 'emptyCard';
    } else if (strZoomin =='zoomin') {
        return 'zoomin';
    } else if (card.data.length == 0) {
        return 'emptyCard';
    }
};
```

**HTML**:

```
ng-class="vm.getcardClass(card, vm.zoomin)"
```

NOTE: Replace `vm` with your controller object.